# Is it standards-compliant to style the <html> node?

Tags: html, css, standards

I am working on a website theme. I want to use a repeating background on the `<html>` node so I can have another background overlapping it on the `<body>` node. Otherwise, I would add the first background to the `<body>` node and then have the second background on a nested `<div>` with 100% width/height inside it. I am going for a full-browser repeating pattern that will be visible no matter how the browser is resized. See my examples.

Desired:

```
<html> <!-- background: url("...") repeat; width: 100%; height: 100%; -->
  <body> <!-- background: url("...") repeat-x; width: 100%; height: 100%; -->
```

Not allowed by specification? Not a good idea because of browser quirks? Work-around:

```
<html> <!-- width: 100%; height: 100%; -->
  <body> <!-- background: url("...") repeat; width: 100%; height: 100%; -->
    <div> <!-- background: url("...") repeat-x; width: 100%; height: 100%; -->
```

It is working in FF5 and IE7/8/9. But is there is a specification that says to not add style to the `<html>` node? Is there a particular browser I should watch out for, such as IE6, that will cause me to revert to the alternative if I try this?

**EDIT:** I am using a proper `<!DOCTYPE html...>` declaration (XHTML 1.0 Tansitional). The width/height on the `html` node is mostly for clarity of my background pattern's intentions. (Thanks @veryfoolish)

**EDIT 2:** I know CSS3 supports multiple backgrounds per node and @merryprankster's comment shows me how to simulate that with CSS 2.1 (thanks!), but I really need to know if HTML/CSS according to specification restricts anything "visual" on the `<html>` node, which in practice is generally used as an invisible box surrounding the `<body>` tag. Is there a reason why no one takes advantage of the `<html>` node's guaranteed existence,  by applying CSS styles to it (not just cascaded properties, like `font-size`)?

Comment: may be more appropriate for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Something inside me says to be wary about doing this - I'm not sure exactly why it is. I'd rather play it save and use a wrapper div.

Comment: FWIW, you do not need to use multiple elements in order to overlay backgrounds - you can use pseudo-selectors `:before` and `:after`. For example, see  http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Comment: @merryprankster I didn't know that. Unfortunately, it won't work for IE6/7, which I still need to support by at least having the theme look reasonably correct. +1 for the great idea, which I will probably use another time.

Comment: @Sinan I thought webmasters.stackexchange.com was for operating web servers, SEO, etc. Should website programming questions go there, too? I wasn't sure. I guess this technically isn't a "programming" question. Could a mod please migrate my question to webmasters.stackexchange.com, if that is a better fit?

Answer (score 3):

Use of things like `html { height: 100%; }` is all but ubiquitous; I see no problem with this usage (and a quick gander at sundry CSS Technical Recommendations suggest it’s sound syntax).

And this goes without saying—esp. since your question is about standards—but make sure you use a DTD (e.g., `<!DOCTYPE html>`) because a quick Google search sez IE6/7 will only render stylized HTML tags if in so-called standards mode.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I updated my question to reflect that we are on the same page. I also clarified by intent somewhat with my second edit. I still cannot figure out if styling the `<html>` node is a bad idea or just commonly overlooked.